# Shopware 6: Reload a route after saving function using the Administration

Tags: javascript, shopware, shopware6

I want to reload the route "sw.vehicles.list" after saving the entity vehicles. How can I do that ?
I have used `window.reload()` but it doesn't work !
Could you help me please ?

```
methods: {
        async onStartProcess(e) {

            this.isLoading = true;
 
            this.sw_vehicles = this.repository.create(Shopware.Context.api);
                            
            if(data[i]['name']) this.sw_vehicles.vehicleName= data[i]['name'];
            if(data[i]['type']) this.sw_vehicles.vehicleType = data[i]['type'];
        
            this.repository.save(this.sw_vehicles, Shopware.Context.api).then(() => {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.processSuccess = true;
                        this.$router.push({ name: 'sw.vehicles.list' });
                                
                        // reload the page "sw.vehicles.list"
               }).catch((exception) => {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.createNotificationError({ 
                            title: this.$t('sw-vehicles.import.errorTitle'),
                            message: exception
                        });
              });
             }                    
            }                  
          } 
        },

        saveFinish(e) {
            this.processSuccess = false;
        },
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to reload to full page? Thanks to Vue JS the data bindings should update automatically when changing them. But you can / should reload the entity from the repository as described here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/admin/2020-09-17-the-best-practice-to-always-re-fetch-the-data-after-saving

Comment: When I import a CSV file for example, the page will be redirected to the list page with 2 entries, while the file contains about ten entries that I receive them only when I refresh the list page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't want to reload the entire page when using a reactive framework, but still this should to the trick:

```js
window.location.reload(true)
```

The boolean argument is for Firefox only to break the cache.